# HTTP GET works, but other HTTP methods return 401 - Angular 9 Asp.Net Core 3.1 JWT authorization

Tags: angular, http, asp.net-core, post, jwt

Symptoms:

1. JWT authorization works correctly. It does not allow unauthorized users to access protected methods, and correctly authorizes users with a valid JWT Bearer header (for GET methods)
2. HTTP GET requests act as-expected.
3. HTTP POST, PUT and DELETE requests formed in the same way return 401.
4. This is only a problem in the browser. Fiddler (postman) is able to POST successfully.

**A WORKING GET REQUEST:**

Client-side:

```
this.http.get(this.baseUrl + "ControllerName/MethodName/" + id, {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + token
  })
}).subscribe(response => {
  console.log(response);
}, err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Server-side:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult MethodName(Guid id)
    {
        return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(id));
    }
```

**A POST REQUEST WHICH RETURNS 401:**

Client-side:

```
this.http.post(this.baseUrl + "ControllerName/MethodName/" + id, {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + token
  })
}).subscribe(response => {
  console.log(response);
}, err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Server-side:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public IActionResult MethodName(Guid id)
{
    return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(id));
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to why an authorized GET request would work, but a POST request that is formed the same, for the same method would not?

Comment: Did you compare the actual requests that go over the line, from the browser vs. from Postman? Since you already mentioned Fiddler, that should be very easy to do. What differences do you find?

Comment: In your example you call a post method without sending any data, but post require something, not like get that only require url

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! Adding another parameter worked, as pc_coder suggested is working right away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below. in angular in post method first param is url, second param is body third one is options. send null as body

```
  this.http.post(this.baseUrl + "ControllerName/MethodName/" + id,null, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + token
      })
    }).subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response);
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

Comment: I had the same problem, the 'null' part after + id, had helped me. Probably the serverside expected a body to be included, but wasn't there.